# simple description of General inverse function?

Tags: inverse-function, monte-carlo, simulation

If **x** from a random variable $X \in R $ with a continuous distribution $F$ and $u \in [0,1]$. Then general inverse function is defined as

$$ F^{-}(u) = inf \{ x;  F(x) \geq  u \} $$

There is any simply explanation for this general inverse function. So that students from other discipline can understand this definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will denote the function by $\Phi$ and make some remarks.

---

1) It is better to go for $u\in(0,1)$.

This because $\Phi(u)\in\mathbb R$ for every $u\in(0,1)$ which is not necessarily true if $u=0$ or $u=1$.

2) It is not necessary to demand that $F$ is continuous.

3) Characteristic is the relation:$$F(x)\geq u\iff x\geq \Phi(u)$$Based on that relation it can be shown that random variable $\Phi(U)$ - where $U$ has uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ - will have $F$ as CDF.

4) $\Phi$ can be recognized as a [weak inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_inverse) of $F$. We have:$$F\circ\Phi\circ F=F\text{ and }\Phi\circ F\circ\Phi=\Phi$$

Comment: Dear @drhab, Who one can write this $$ F^{-}(u) = inf \{ x;  F(x) \geq  u \} $$ function and understand the logic behind the function?

Comment: Any one who can understand the logic of inverse function. In many cases (if $F $ is continuous and strictly increasing ) it is not more than that. If $F $ is not bijective and still search for a function that "looks like inverse " as much as possible then you will arrive at this function. It is exploited that $F $ is increasing and continuous on the right.